# How to allow the Jqplot Data Point labels to accept day-month-year in the x-axis

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, jqplot

i am working on thr  Chart with Point Labels inside my asp.net mvc as mentioned in this link http://www.jqplot.com/tests/point-labels.php , my view looks the following:-

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About Us";
}
@section scripts{
<script src="../../Scripts/jqplot/jqplot.barRenderer.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jqplot/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jqplot/jqplot.pointLabels.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    }
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

var line1 = [[1,14], [2,32]];
  var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [line1], {
      title: 'Chart with Point Labels',
      seriesDefaults: {
        showMarker:false,
        pointLabels: { show:true }
      }
  });
});
    });
</script>

<div id = "chart1">
</div>
```

currently the x-axis will have 1 & 2 and also the numbers between them such as (1.1,1.2,etc) ,, so how i can modify this chart to include the following:-

1. i need the x-axis to be day-month-year. currently if insert something like `var line1  =[['23-May-08', 578.55], ['20-Jun-08', 566.5]` the chart will not be displayed
2. i do not want to display any intermediate number between the x-axis values i specify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var line1=[['2008-09-30 4:00PM',4], ['2008-10-30 4:00PM',6.5], ['2008-11-30 4:00PM',5.7], ['2008-12-30 4:00PM',9], ['2009-01-30 4:00PM',8.2]];
  var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [line1], {
    title:'Default Date Axis',
    axes:{xaxis:{renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer}},
    series:[{lineWidth:4, markerOptions:{style:'square'}}]
  });
```

ref: http://www.jqplot.com/tests/date-axes.php

Comment: I hope this is what you need. At first I thought you are using flot library.

Comment: it will work well but i have added "pointLabels: { show: true}" to show the labels. BR